# Use dinamic variables in tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a variable that comes from the api and i need to use it to style the page.

[I know cant do this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

```
 <button
    type="button"
    // href={"www.linktooapp.com"}
    className={`hover:bg-[${darkerVariableNameColor}] <- this
    h-45
    inline-flex
    w-full
    items-center
    justify-center
    rounded-[10px]
    p-2
    font-bold
    focus:outline-none
    `}
>
  Saiba Mais
</button>
```

I resolve the problem with the bgColor but how i will do with the hover ?

```
 <button
    type="button"
    style={{
      backgroundColor: VariableNameColor, <- this
    }}
    // href={"www.linktooapp.com"}
    className={`hover:bg-[${darkerVariableNameColor}]
     h-45
     inline-flex
     w-full
     items-center
     justify-center
     rounded-[10px]
     p-2
     font-bold
     focus:outline-none
    `}
>
  Saiba Mais
</button>
```

Comment: Where is `darkerVariableNameColor` coming from? Maybe you can add a tailwind plugin for that

Comment: Comes from "my" api 
Its a page that are customizable by the user so is basicaly everthing dinamic

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you should not construct class names dynamically (see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Instead, you should use a map object like so:

```js
const colorVariants = {
  blue: 'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-400',
  red: 'bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-400',
}

return (
 <button
    type="button"
    className={`${colorVariants[color]}`}
>
  Saiba Mais
</button>
);
```

Comment: Yeah?
I have said that i know that i cant do this way.
The problem is that is a dinamic variable that comes from my api and i cant map it bc the use chose the color